# Rolling_apply and scipy nanmean behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I've got a dataframe called dF:

```
                      Twa_mean
Date_Time                    
2007-01-01 07:00:00       6.5
2007-01-01 07:10:00       6.4
2007-01-01 07:20:00       6.4
2007-01-01 07:30:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:40:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:50:00       NaN
```

I´m trying to obtain the rolling mean (window=2), but without considering the NaNs, so, I use the nanmean function of scipy.stats:

```
import scipy.stats as st

f=lambda x: st.nanmean(x)

d=pd.rolling_apply(dF,2,f)
```

However, I´m obtaining this:

```
                     Twa_mean
Date_Time                    
2007-01-01 07:00:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:10:00      6.45
2007-01-01 07:20:00      6.40
2007-01-01 07:30:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:40:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:50:00       NaN
```

It´s like st.nanmean were not ignoring the NaNs, what´s happening??

I´d expect this:

```
                     Twa_mean
Date_Time                    
2007-01-01 07:00:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:10:00      6.45
2007-01-01 07:20:00      6.40
2007-01-01 07:30:00      6.40
2007-01-01 07:40:00       NaN
2007-01-01 07:50:00       NaN
```

Comment: What is your expected output? This is the output I would expect. Perhaps you want to remove all the NaN? In that case use `.dropna()` .

Comment: Any reason you aren't using pandas' rolling mean? `pd.rolling_mean(df, 2)`?

Comment: Oh, after your edit, I understand. That is also what I would expect.

Comment: I´m not using it because such function, whenever there is a NaN, the mean is equal to NaN and I want to calculate the mean, even if there are some NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that pandas rolling mean will cover the case you gave. You just need to specify the `minimum_periods` argument to `rolling_mean`

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
                       1
0                       
2007-01-01 07:00:00  6.5
2007-01-01 07:10:00  6.4
2007-01-01 07:20:00  6.4
2007-01-01 07:30:00  NaN
2007-01-01 07:40:00  NaN
2007-01-01 07:50:00  NaN

In [54]: pd.rolling_mean(df, 2, min_periods=1)
Out[54]: 
                        1
0                        
2007-01-01 07:00:00  6.50
2007-01-01 07:10:00  6.45
2007-01-01 07:20:00  6.40
2007-01-01 07:30:00  6.40
2007-01-01 07:40:00   NaN
2007-01-01 07:50:00   NaN
```

This isn't quite what you had for your expected, but I'd say it's more consistent. You were expecting `NaN` for the first one, presumably since you just had the 1 observation. But for the later ones you were setting the mean equal to a single observation (due to the NaNs). If you really want this you can go through and set the first `n` observations (`n=1` in this case) equal to `NaN` afterwards (`res = pd.rolling_mean(df, 2, min_periods=1); res.iloc[:n] = np.nan`).